# Find where the difference of vector is larger than 1

Tags: matlab

I can't figure out why this bit of code isn't working:

I have a vector j like this

> j=[1;2;4;13;14;19;20]

I am trying to do

```
for i=2:7
    j1=find(j(i)==(j(i-1)+1)
end
```

This should give me a j1 of [2,5,7] right? For some reason it's giving me a j1 of either [1] or [0]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, also I am not tied to using find. I just need the indices of j where there is a discontinuity, i.e. for the j I posted it should tell me where it jumps from 1,2 to 4 and from 4 to 13,14 etc.

Comment: To start with, since the line with the find in it is not even valid matlab syntax, how can we answer? Note the parens don't match up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want in a much easier way:

```
indexes = find( diff(j) > 1)
```

Regarding your code:

1. `find` can be vectorized, no need to use `for` loop
2. You keep on reassigning `j1`. Instead, you can do `j1(end+1) = ..`